# LWC - How to change picklist

Tags: lightning-web-components, js, queryselector

How do I change the picklist value to Sold automatically from my JS in LWC?

Here's what I have:

```
   this.template.querySelector("c-single-select-picklist[data-id='" 
                                + Id +"'][data-type='status']").value = 'Sold';
```

In Chrome Dev Tools - Debug mode, I can see that the picklist is set to 'Sold', but it's not showing to the User in the picklist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using lightning combobox in your singleSelectPicklist component, you have to ensure that the combobox option includes an object `{label: 'Sold', value: 'Sold'}`. The value has to match the value you are setting, label can be anything.

Also worth checking that `value` is marked with the `@api` flag in the singleSelectPicklist component, or else it cannot receive the update from parent. Please also check that the `value` is used as the picklist value

If the error still occurs, kindly show more of your code so I can understand it better and provide a more accurate answer.

Comment: It's some complex custom code. Just seeing your process of thought gave me the foundation I needed to find the un-obvious variable with @api on it. Problem solved.